# How to calculate, if any cells in a range contain a value then do a sum otherwise display nothing

Tags: excel, if-statement, range, cell, formula

I'm trying to create a formula in Excel which checks if any cell in a range of cells is empty then display nothing. If any 1 of these cells contains a value then do a sum of the cell range

e.g
I have values in cells D11 to J11. In cell, L11 I am trying to calculate the sum of D11:J11 only if any 1 of my 7 cells (D11 to J11) contain a value

I have tried the following:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(D11:J11,""),"",SUM(D11:J11))
```

However, what my formula is doing currently is checking if any of my cells from D11:J11 is blank then it doesn't do the sum.

Background:
I'm trying to create a timesheet invoice so if there are any hours worked in a day then L11 calculates the total amount of hours worked in a week otherwise display nothing

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In L11 put your sum formula,

```
=SUM(D11:J11)
```

Format the L11 cell as,

```
general;general;;
```

Comment: unfortuantly this isn't what I want. L11 will still show 0. I want the cell to remain blank

Comment: No it won't. Please follow the directions as I've outlined them above.

Comment: apologies for doubting you. this has worked. Thank you

Comment: extremely clever!!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - well I had to offer up something a little more exciting than `=IF(COUNT(D11:J11), SUM(D11:J11), TEXT(,))`.

Comment: However if **D11** was ***1*** and **E11** was ***-1*** the sum would be zero and should be displayed.

Comment: That's true; I suppose an hour could be negative as some sort of work penalty. The number (zero) is still there for other calculations.